# Is it possible to determine AudioHAL from AudioFlinger code in Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, android-hardware

Audio HAL can be different in each system. How to determine the AudioHAL file for a system? Is it possible to determine it from AudioFlinger code?

Comment: What do you mean by _"determine"_? Exactly which information are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to find the AudioHAL file.

Comment: Which file? The `audio.primary` shared object? It's probably located in `/system/lib/hw`. You can look at the [audioflinger code](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/services/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp?h=aosp-new/master) and [libhardware code](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/libhardware/tree/hardware.c?h=kitkat) to see how it loads the audio modules.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find a vendor specific AudioHAL file for a device. I know that it will be inside ../android/vendor directory that will implement ../libhardware/include/hardware/audio.h functionalities. I can find it easily by printing debug logs. I was asking for the logic to idetify the HAL file by looking at the AudioFlinger code only.

Comment: You mean the [audio_hw_hal source file](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/qcom/audio/tree/alsa_sound/audio_hw_hal.cpp?h=jb_mr1)? Where you'll find it depends on the platform AFAIK, and I'm not sure if the audioflinger code will tell you anything about the location of the audio HAL source code. Why not use `find` / `grep` in your repo to find the files?